# Addling Line Break in Vim with Substitution

Tags: regex, vim, macvim

There is a really helpful article on Vim's wiki [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Add_a_newline_after_given_patterns) that is nearly exactly what I want to do, I think I'm just missing something small.

I would like to take this line:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

and make it into:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, 
                    as: resource_name, 
                    url: session_path(resource_name)
                    ) do |f| %>
```

However when I run:
`/[(,)]`
`:s//\r&/g`

I get:

```
<%= simple_form_for
(resource
, as: resource_name
, url: session_path
(resource_name
)
) do |f| %>
```

I need the linebreaks to happen AFTER the commmas and I'm unsure the regex to provide to make that happen.  Thoughts?

Comment: Do you understand what the `&` does? (Hint its same as `\0`)

Comment: @FDinoff thank youf or the hint! I got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you would replace every comma by a comma followed by a newline.

```
:s/,/&\r/g
```

If you also want to separate every pair of two `))` by a newline, you can do this.

```
%s/))/)\r)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @FDinoff !  I figured it out, it was simply rearranging my search & replace with:

`:s//&\r/g`